# SSRS sub report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a weekly report that is pretty basic.

> Engineer, Account number, Name, Date etc.

The twist that I am not sure how to accomplish is that the user needs to see a list of attachments based on the above criteria.  I have a query which creates a single row for each attachment.

The layout I am looking is per the attached image.  What I need to do is take the Attachment Name and create a row for each attachment under the existing tablix based on all of the other columns.  Basically what is happening is that for each SIOA name, multiple attachments are being created.  I just need to see them listed below for each occurrence.  I hope this makes some sense.

Since I **cannot** post the image, I have a basic tablix with 11 columns.  One of the columns is Attachment.  I need the attachments grouped as separate rows below the other 10 columns.  This way the user will see only one row for each project and multiple rows of the attachments.

Comment: I think you forgot to attach an image. As a new user, you may have to link to the image instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think the simplest solution is to make a new row group based on the Account# (or whatever unique ID you may have for each record). Then put all your fields except the attachment field at the group level, and leave only the attachment field at the details level. That way you will get one row per group, with all the attachment rows listed beneath that group. More information on creating row groups [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dd255263.aspx). You could also get fancy with a [drilldown action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dd207141.aspx) if you wanted to.